# How to determine a class has implement a specific interface or not

Tags: c#, oop

Suppose I have a class like

```
interface ISampleInterface
{
  void SampleMethod();
}

class ImplementationClass : ISampleInterface
{
// Explicit interface member implementation: 
void ISampleInterface.SampleMethod()
{
    // Method implementation.
}

static void Main()
{
    // Declare an interface instance.
    ISampleInterface obj = new ImplementationClass();

    // Call the member.
    obj.SampleMethod();
}
}
```

From the main method how could I determine that the `ImplementationClass` class implements `ISampleInterface` before writing the code like below

```
SampleInterface obj = new ImplementationClass();
obj.SampleMethod();
```

is there any way....please discuss. thanks.

Comment: Well if you need to know that, presumably you have *something* at execution time - do you have an object, or just the name of the type, or what?

Comment: Erm look at the code or metadata for the class

Comment: @JonSkeet maybe i'm wrong but I thought OP was asking how to determine it at design time.

Comment: @BenRobinson: Basically it's unclear...

Comment: I assume that "before writing the code `SampleInterface obj = new ImplementationClass();`" means, that he has no object instance and wants to apply a test on a type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use reflection:

```
bool result = typeof(ISampleInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ImplementationClass));
```

Answer (score 13):

The [`is` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) is a good solution for this. You can test if an object is an interface, or another class for that matter. You would do something like this:

```
if (obj is ISampleInterface)
{
     //Yes, obj is compatible with ISampleInterface
}
```

If you don't have an instance of the object at runtime, but a `Type`, you can use IsAssignableFrom:

```
Type type = typeof(ISampleInterface);
var isassignable = type.IsAssignableFrom(otherType);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    public static bool IsImplementationOf(this Type checkMe, Type forMe)
    {
        foreach (Type iface in checkMe.GetInterfaces())
        {
            if (iface == forMe)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Call it using:

```
if (obj.GetType().IsImplementationOf(typeof(SampleInterface)))
    Console.WriteLine("obj implements SampleInterface");
```

Answer (score 1):

When you hard-code the implementation class, you know what interface(s) it implements, so you can simply look at the source code or the documentation to know which interfaces a class implements.

If you are receiving an object of an unknown type, you have several ways to check for an implementation of an interface:

```
void Test1(object a) {
    var x = a as IMyInterface;
    if (x != null) {
        // x implements IMyInterface, you can call SampleMethod
    }
}

void Test2(object a) {
    if (a is IMyInterface) {
        // a implements IMyInterface
        ((IMyInterface)a).SampleMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One pattern (recommended by [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182271%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) is

```
SampleInterface i = myObject as SampleInterface;
if (i != null) {
    // MyObject implements SampleInterface
}
```